# Theano error when using Masking layer with keras v2

Tags: keras

I've just switch to the new keras API and modify all my call to respect the new API.

I have an error from theano during fit (using fit_generator):

```
theano.gof.fg.MissingInputError: ("An input of the graph, used to compute Elemwise{neq,no_inplace}(/masking_1_input, DimShuffle{x,x,x}.0), was not provided and not given a value.Use the Theano flag exception_verbosity='high',for more information on this error.", /masking_1_input)
```

The error disappears when I suppress the Masking layer.

My network was working perfectly before the move to keras 2.

The network follow a siamese model, it is composed as follow:

The core (duplicated part of the siamese) is a sequential composed of:

- a Masking layer
- an LSTM (with return_sequences set to False)
- 4 Dense layers (with Dropout layers between)

The siamese is a functional model composed like this:

- 2 inputs attached to the same instance of the core layer
- one outputs using a lambda (a simple euclidean distance)

The loss is a custom contrastive loss.

The main siamese architecture, together with the euclidean distance and contrastive loss are inspired by keras siamese example (https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/examples/mnist_siamese_graph.py)

I've tried a more simple example (just Masking/LSTM/Dense without lambda and custom loss) but can't reproduce the error.

Do I miss something or is it a bug due to the API change ?

**Edit:** I've put the code (only network creation) here https://gist.github.com/slashvar/286cfbeed568a70d1f29e4fa77d467b4

Comment: Have you found any solution?

Comment: Not yet, but I guess the problem lies in the lambda layer. I'm currently investigating the masking attribute of this layer, but don't had time to do it yet.

Comment: thank you. I've also tried masking layer with timedistributed layer in keras. you can find it here https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/4786#issuecomment-294232716 . maybe it helps.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately doesn't seem to be related. I don't use timedistributed. Anyway, the problem doesn't seems to be in my lambda layer (I've done a simple exp with a similar architecture (masking, lstm and lambda) and it works … ), the remaining tricky part is the custom loss function. What puzzle me is that it was working before Keras v2 …